# angularjs does not update scope object that changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular controller contains array **named** that updated by Google Maps api.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var items = [
        "arizona", "texas"
    ];

    $scope.places = items;
}
```

I have bind **items** array to my scope variable named **places**.
Google Maps api changes items implicitly, but changes does not appear in view page.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    <p>{{places.length}}</p>
</div>
```

If I add or remove item in **$cope.places**, it updates. But does not update if I add item in **items** array. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You're not showing the most important part of your code - where you update `items`

Comment: you need to apply digest cycle if you doing manipulation in angular scope variables

Comment: @pankajparkar - isn't that only the case if you're updating scope variables "outside" of angular?

Comment: @Adam, it sounds like the scope variables are being updated outside of Angular. It sounds like they are being updated by the Google Maps API.

Comment: @Adam its more common problem..scope variable doesn't get update when you modify scope from Google Map API events

Answer (score 0):

Make items a $scope variable, or ditch items and just get Google Maps API to update $scope.places

Comment: `$scope.places` references the same object in memory as `items`. The identifier you use to reference that object (by using `items` or `$scope.places`) to update it doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree, which is why i said just ditch 'items'. Based on the code in the OP, items "seems" unnecessary.

Comment: Then you also know that by simply doing that, it will not solve the OPs problem.

Comment: Based on the code he has posted, it will. If i have $scope.places, and i update it, the view will update

Comment: Based on the code the OP posted, if `items` is updated **inside an angular process**, then the view will also update. The OP isn't showing where/how `items` is updated, which is where this problem really is occurring.

Comment: @Adam If  `items` is updated by assigning a new value to it then the view won't update and your very first statement may turn out wrong eventually. But as you said: We don't know how `items` is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably oversimplifying this, but Angular essentially polls for changes. It does it in a smart way that helps with performance, but if values are changed outside the purview of Angular, then Angular is not immediately aware of them.

Basically, whenever Angular executes any code (`ng-click` event for example), it checks for changes after your code is executed. If the Google Maps API is changing the data, then Angular is not aware of these changes until it checks again.

The best solution would be to let Angular know when these changes happen (hopefully the Google API has a hook for this), this is usually accomplished by calling `$scope.$apply()`, if not,  you can always use Angular's `$interval` service to run a method occasionally, the method doesn't need to actually do anything, but after it runs, Angular will check for changes.